# Auto refresh data in ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0

I am using ajax UpdatePanel in my asp.net page, and I wanted to know can I auto refresh data in my gridview control?

Comment: is it a time based refresh you want or after an event?

Comment: ideally, whenever a new record is added in the database. It could be timer based too (just to keep things simple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this page: [auto-postback-or-refresh-page-for-every-defined-time-interval](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2008/09/05/auto-postback-or-refresh-page-for-every-defined-time-interval.aspx)

Using a timer is the simpliest way.

```
<asp:Timer id="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000">
```

Comment: that was pretty easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `Timer`.